# Sum deep values in a multidimensional using variable keys in path

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have array like this :

```
$rincian7[$kode3][$kode4][$kode5][$idjudul][$idrincian]['trincian'] = $price;
```

I want to sum `$price` for every `$kode3`.

Is that possible?

Comment: There is no [mcve] here. This question is Unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**PHP**

```
$p = 0;
foreach ($rincian7 as $o => $k){
    $p += $k[$kode4][$kode5][$idjudul][$idrincian]['trincian'];
}
echo $p;
```